# I want to disable a Image in webview. I think we can block the URL of image from loading, but How to achieve it

Tags: java, android, webview

Link which I want to block https://learningwithsajal.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/PicsArt_06-24-07.49.43-removebg-preview.png

I am also adding code of my MainActivity.java

```
package com.learning.withsajal;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String websiteURL = "https://learningwithsajal.xyz/"; // sets web url
    private WebView webview;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if( ! CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(this)) //returns true if internet available
        {
            //if there is no internet do this
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet Connection, Chris",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("No internet connection available")
                    .setMessage("Please Check you're Mobile data or Wifi network.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    //.setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

        }
        else
        {
            //Webview stuff
            webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webview.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
            webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());

        }    
}
```

What is solution of this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi to disable the images in `webView` you can use this code:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
```

Comment: I don't want to disable all images, I want to disable a particular image.

Comment: That isn't possible in android studio. Need to be done in the forehand. What you can do, is to set an empty LinearLayout, when getting the page. That the image you don't want is getting hidden. Hope that helped a bit, even it's not what you wanted to hear. Cheers. :)